# DBExpress Unknown error code 65535

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Delphi 7. Firebird 2.1.

I am using TSQLDataSet, TSQLDataSetProvider and TClientDataSet. This architecture has worked for me for a long, long time.

Today it started to give me this error: **DBExpress Unknown error code 65535**, not really clarifying.

I am able to set a SQL in the TSQLDataSet and add all fields in the Fields Editor.

The error occurs when I try to add all fields in the ClientDataSet, in design time. There is no code of mine involved.

I know it os way too litle information but really I don´t even know where to start digging.

**Notes**

- I recently installed Delphi XE2 to start migrating

Comment: Start with identifying which code is causing the error. You've provided nothing more to go on here to use to help you. Figure out what code or SQL is running when the error happens, and then examine that location to see if you can figure out why it's causing the error to happen. If you can't figure out why, edit your question here and provide the code, and as much additional info as you can, and perhaps someone can help. As is, I'd suspect it's going to be very difficult for anyone to provide much assistance.

Comment: You are correct. There were no info about when the error occured. I added some info now. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post info on the fields (name, datatype, etc.) that the SQL query is returning? It appears you have some field type that is supported in the `TSQLDataSet` that isn't supported in the `TClientDataSet`. If possible, can you edit your post to provide the schema definition? If not, try adding one field at a time to the `TClientDataSet` - if you can, the one causing the problem should be easy to identify.

Comment: I don´t think it is a dataType issue. I think something in my environment changed that is causing the error. I think that because it used to work for me here and it is happening all over my project right now.

Comment: Yes, but @KenWhite can still be right. If installing XE2 means you also installed a new firebird driver, and that happens to be a 64 bit one or it may support something differently than the old one. Also the value 65535 is pretty suspect with regard to bitness and/or signed-ness as it is on an exact 2-power boundary and may be the result of High(SomeIntegerType) + 1 which would previously overflow to -1 but is now happy to return 65535.

Comment: @MarjanVenema, thanks. :) I was about to point that out, but you did it much better than what I was writing. (And more quickly, too.) :)

Comment: Clarifying comments. Thank you Marjan Venema and Ken White. Will try some other things here. Thank you very much.

Comment: And it happened to be the connection string. it was like "localhost:c:\mypath\sgl.fdb", replacing it by "c:\mypath\sgl.fdb" made it work.

Comment: This happened at work when we tried to execute a stored procedure twice in the same session, it created a temp table and didn't drop it. Another one happened when we had the `row_number()` OLAP function in a query, and the database didn't support bigint. 

My point is, DBx is pretty bad at showing errors and the problem could be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have Firebird / Interbase clients DLL hell. For Firebird you should use `fbclient.dll`, for Interbase - `gds32.dll`. If you does not follow to this rule, then DBMS API may return a misterious error. And dbExpress driver may have no good idea, what to do with this error. Then it returns another misterious error - 65535.

Probably (again, because no information) you had `fbclient.dll` renamed to `gds32.dll` to make Interbase Borland dbEpress driver happy. Then Delphi XE2 installed a real `gds32.dll` or it was installed as part of Interbase installation (do you ?). The current real Interbase `gds32.dll` is not compatible with your Firebird server.

You have to verify what DLL loads dbExpress driver, using SysMon or IDE Event Log. Then check what is this DLL. Then probably you will need to restore your `gds32.dll`.